# Head rotation according to weapon sight

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I have a 2D game and I'm working on head rotation with my newbie coding skills. My **Player** has child sprite object called `DefaultPistol` (which is the whole arm and pistol attached to it) and it has a `Weapon` script. The arm turns 360 (centered from the shoulder) in the scene.

What I need is for my player turn his `Head` wherever arm turns (the `Head` is also another child sprite object attached to Player like `DefaultPistol`) but not like rotating the head, I just simply want to mirror the head to face left or right.

I tried setting the head's x scale to 1 or -1, but it didn't work and I couldn't find what is the problem. (I also checked the inspector if I didn't attach anything, but everything is in order as far as I can see)

[image: Diagram of head flip]

Here is my Weapon. You can see where I tried to implement this in `Flip`. How can I fix this?

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject projectile;
    public Transform shotPoint;
    public float timeBetweenShots;
    private Animator cameraAnim;

    private float shotTime;
    private bool facingRight;
    public GameObject head;


    private void Start()
    {
        cameraAnim = Camera.main.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {   //this code paragraph here is calculating the shotPoint player rotation
        Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + 90, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = rotation;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Time.time >= shotTime)
            {
                Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
                cameraAnim.SetTrigger("shake");
                shotTime = Time.time + timeBetweenShots;
            }

        }

    }

    private void Flip(float horizontal)
    {
        if (horizontal > 0 && !facingRight || horizontal < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            head.transform.localScale = new Vector3();
            theScale.x *= -1;

            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not calling the `Flip` method anywhere. It also seems to turn the localScale of the head to a `new Vecotr3()`, which would be a `0:0:0` vector, which would make the head disappear. It then mirrors the scale of the object the script is on, not the head.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know where I can call the Flip method. Also, can you be more spesific for solution in view of the fact that I am newbie on coding, please :)

Comment: Well, when you don't call the method, then it can't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `SpriteRenderer`'s `FlipX` property.You dont need any kind of `Vector` scale operations just simply use `SpriteRenderer`'s builtin property

**Example**

```
public class CharacterHeadFlipScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer characterHeadSpriteRenderer; // just drag and drop the sprite renderer of your character's head via editor
    
    void Update()
    {
        /*
         * First get the current mouse world position
         */
        Vector2 mouseScreenPosition = Input.mousePosition; // gets the current position of the mouse in screen space coordinates (Pixels)
        Vector2 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouseScreenPosition); //Converts screen space coordinate to world coordinates

        /*
         * Get the character's body position
         * Im asuming you add this script to the character you want to flip its head
         */
        Vector2 characterPosition = this.transform.position;

        /*
         * Check if mouse is on the right side of your character or on the left side
         * I will assume that your character's default head direction is the right side
         */
        if(mouseWorldPosition.x > characterPosition.x) // mouse on the right side of the character
        {
            /*
             * This means character should look to default direction(right side) so we should disable FlipX of the SpriteRenderer
             */
            characterHeadSpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
        else // mouse on the left side of the character
        {
            /*
             * This means character should look to opposite direction(left side)
             */
            characterHeadSpriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I dealt with the situation. Now Player turns his head wherever his arm position.

Comment: Actually now there is a little problem occured, my player is also moving. When he goes to right side, code working very good, but when he runs left side, his weapon_arm and head are become opposite.